# Add a string value to a DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net

I have a `DateTimePicker` with a custom format as "`hh:mm:ss`". How do I add a string containing a value of "`16:00:00`" to this DTP?

Comment: `myDate.ToString("hh:mm:ss")` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim cnv As String = "16:54:06"  
    Dim CTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(cnv)
    MyDateTimePicker.Value = CTime
```